# Regular expression to get url without subpage

Tags: javascript, regex, url

What is the right regex for url without subpage?

False: `http://abc.com/subpage`
True: `http://abc.com`

Comment: FYI, what you call "subpage" is the *path* of the URL.

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: That's rather about terminology than language, don't worry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should catch everything that looks like a valid URL. I say "should" because it doesn't check if the TLD is actually real.

```
^(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})\/?$
```

If you want to check for certain TLD's only you can use the following regular expression. Just add more TLD's separating them with the pipe | sign.

```
^(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.(net|org|nl|com|co\.uk)\/?$
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
^https?://([^/]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/?$
```

It will match:

- `http://` or `https://`
- Any character except `/` (1 or more times)
- Ending with `.X` where `X` is 2, 3 or 4 letters.

I tried to make it simple. If you [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=URL+Regex) you will get lots of results that will give you a much more specific regular expression to match URLs.

Comment: that is right but something missing here. It accepts "http://abc" . What about the domain extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-z]{3,5}:\/{2})((?:[\w-]+\.)?[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})$

match 'http://abc.com' -> ['http://abc.com'], ['http://'], ['abc.com']
match 'http://www.abc.com' -> ['http://www.abc.com'], ['http://'], ['www.abc.com']
match 'http://abc.com/test' -> null
```

You can also use `{2,6}` instead of `{2,4}` at the end if you have to take TLDs like `.museum` into account.